# What file extension is usually on a game's save file?

Tags: python, pygame, file-extension

I'm currently making a game in python which you can save your maps/worlds. I was wondering what extension is generally used used on a file which saved the world's terrain, stats, players,  etc.

Comment: I think you can use whatever you want.  Starcraft uses .sc2

Comment: One common, generic extension is .sav

Comment: Everything I've found seems to suggest that it doesn't matter, it's what goes in it, the extension could be anything you like as long as your game can read it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real "usual extension", since there are so many different formats. Take a look at Minecraft for instance - it doesn't even have *one* save file per world, but a save directory.

Inside of this directory, it uses different file extensions (`.dat`, `.mca`, `.json`). Another file extension would be `.sav` or `.mgz` as used by Age of Empires II.

So, just use whatever you feel like.

Comment: Worth also bearing in mind that it doesn't need to be limited to three letters any more - the three-letter extension space is far too crowded already...